# SQL Scripts in Continuous Delivery tool or framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, tfs, continuous-integration

I'm not sure if this question is duplicated, but I have not been able to find an answer for this

I'm trying to implement Continuous Delivery best practices and deploy my SQL Scripts automatically, I'm using SQL Server 2008 and TFS 2012

Most of the database scripts are in the project numbered sequentially, each one of them is atomic

My SQL Scripts are stored in TFS as well in a different Visual Studio solution in a Database Project actually.

And I would like to find a consistent way (best practice) in order to fetch automatically the SQL scripts from these database projects and run them depending on the environment selected.

Is there any framework or tool that could help me out to achieve this?

Or could you guys point me in the right direction?

We are actually looking for a consistent, standard and reusable way to accomplish this within the organization because as soon as we are able to implement this solution for one project, we are planning to do the same for all the rest of the internal projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBDeploy.NET works great; it uses numbered scripts to apply database changes. It supports rollbacks if you write the rollback scripts.  I've used it on my last two projects. http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdeploy-net/.

Comment: DB-Deploy, liquidbase, etc are great for this. Using the numbered scripts allows you to map Databases' incremental, order dependent changes to the 'deploy whatever the latest is' mode common in CD.